# How to Use my browser cookies in c#

Tags: c#

I have c# program and i want request some website and using the cookies file in my system to request the website whit out login page?

Answer (score 1):

```
 A cookie is a small bit of text that accompanies requests and pages as they go between the Web server and browser. The cookie contains information the Web application can read whenever the user visits the site.
```

Follow this Example...

Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "John";
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie("lastVisit");
aCookie.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);